# Serial Printing in QGis 3.0

Tags: qgis, printing, atlas

I want to automatically generate a series of prints following a street for planning communcation lines next to it.

**Requirements:**

- fixed layout
- fixed map scale
- serial print following selected objects of a layer or a set polygon
- text-chart linked with attributes of layers.
- pages should overlap ~5%
- prefer pdf as print output

I noticed I can manually create and print a document with multiple pages and maps using the atlas function.
I'd be fine with a screenshot showing the settings and how to set find these options.

Following image shows in a Index page how it should set up the pages.
The red lines will be drawn as an layer
Is it possible to also get the index page printed in QGis

[image: Index]

A single Page should look like this

[image: Map Page]

This is my current Atlas setting window but I don't see an option to let QGis generate an Atlas by itself with the coverage layer.

[image]

Comment: The Atlas takes care of automating the page creation. You still need to provide it with a coverage layer and automatically generating this is what you're after.

Comment: How do I generate this? I have edited the question so you can see my settings.

Comment: if you want to make a series of maps along your trasse, you will need discret objects which will mark the middle of each map. In your settings you are using trasse itself to control the atlas - if trasse contains only one object, the atlas will generate only one map. you should make a new layer with points (just the middle of each map, like in your sketch 1) an use this for the atlas generation.

Comment: Ok. I have a plugin "locate points along lines" installed for that.

I want to automate the process of Atlas generating as we have 50+ pages every time.

Problem is we are not printing square-shaped so North-South or East-West lines have different possible distances on our A3 Paper.

Example on Landscape:
-100m Point distance: No gaps between maps on N-S lines, but there is huge overlap on E-W
-200m Pointdistance: No overlap on E-W lines but huge gap between N-S maps

Any tips on how to fix this? Deleting unnessecary pages is no option.
Close to constant overlap would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With QGIS 2.18 there is a plugin called 'PolyStrip'.  It creates polygons based on certain settings (width, height, overlap).

Unfortunatly this plugin is not (yet) available in QGIS 3.  There you can create points along line (as @eurojam suggests).  And use them to create the atlas

Comment: Sounds like the solution to the problem.
I'll keep that in my mind and check for it.
Until then a manual solution has to work out I guess.
Thanks !

Comment: you can create the PolyStrip with QGIS 2.18 and load that layer in QGIS 3?